# Embedding Google drive in a Google page

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I am trying to show a specific privately shared drive folder in my Google page. I am using this guide: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/embedding_docslist_in_sites

I am stuck on Step "8. Replace `PASTE_PAGE_URL_HERE` in the method `getPageByUrl()` by the url of your file cabinet."

I have tried every URL combination in "" and I just get a scripting error on the `getPageByUrl()` method.

Answer (score 0):

I just tested this and it seems to work fine for me. Make sure you are using the full URL for your file cabinet page. For example, on my test site, I created a new page using 'file cabinet' in the template dropdown calling it "myfcpage". This gives me a new page with URL: "https://sites.google.com/site/mytestsite/myfcpage". Therefore my function call looks like this:

```
var page = SitesApp.getPageByUrl("https://sites.google.com/site/mytestsite/myfcpage");
```

Comment: Thanks, Now I know you use the site in there. Now every time I run the script I get a duplicate entry on page refresh. would this code be better? http://sitesguide.pjrprojects.co.uk/google-sites/sample-scripts/embed-a-google-apps-folder

Comment: Well, that code seems to be deleting all the list items and repopulating them. Yes, you could do something similar with file cabinet also by doing `var attachments = page.getAttachments();
  for (i in attachments) {
    attachments[i].deleteAttachment();
  }`. Then you would use the original code to add the files back to the file cabinet.

Comment: Unfortunately if you add something directly to the file cabinet that action deletes them and only keeps drive files.

Comment: Yes, that's what it's supposed to do. Delete the files you've previously added to the file cabinet so you can run the script to add them again (without duplicating them). Maybe I'm misunderstanding your question?